# How to add extra attributes specific to a product?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, custom-options

I am trying to figure out how could I achieve the same structure as: http://catalog.uk.toolstore.com/#/?search=0349-0109

[image: The Attribute Table]

The table below the description varies from product to product and it has different attributes. Some of the attributes (like 'Art. no.' or 'Weight') are always there while others vary from product to product (one product has a 'Bits for hex holes' attribute while another does not).

The question is, how could I add extra attributes, specific to a particular product, so on the product page I could see a list of attributes similar to the one in the example?

Answer (score 4):

I had to solve the same issue. The way I handled it was to create tokenized strings in a single attribute and parse them accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In your comment above you state that you don't want to create an attribute set for each product.

You still could create an attribute set that contains all of the attributes that you need. You would then create attributes that don't necessarily need to be filled in.

When you don't want to show these attributes when they are empty, you could apply what is described in [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29469/how-to-hide-empty-attribute-in-any-magento-template). It's basically about filtering out the empty-valued attributes.

Comment: There are so many products with different attributes that it will result in creating hundreds of new attribute sets.

Comment: That's why I described to create one set, possibly containing a lot of attributes. You would then filter out the empty ones programmatically. I haven't done it myself before, so you should try it out for performance testing.

Comment: Not sure if that's reasonable. I need an easy way for a moderator to be able to add extra attributes to a product when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new attribute through install script like this:

```
$installer->addAttribute(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    'attribute_name',
    array(
        'type'                    => 'int',
        'label'                   => 'Attribute Title',
        'input'                   => 'boolean',
        'class'                   => '',
        'group'                   => 'Prices',
        'apply_to'                => 'configurable',
        'global'                  => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'                 => true,
        'required'                => false,
        'user_defined'            => false,
        'default'                 => '',
        'searchable'              => false,
        'filterable'              => false,
        'comparable'              => false,
        'visible_on_front'        => true,
        'unique'                  => false,
    )
);
```

The key thing is:

> 'visible_on_front'        => true,

There is a specific block wich renders all attributes that has that option set to *TRUE*.

Or you can edit the property for already existed attribute from admin page *Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes*:

[image]

Comment: That is not what I am asking. I want each product to have specific attributes (or an ability to quickly add new attributes to a product). For example, one product has attributes a, b and c, while another has a, d and f. I also don't want to be creating a different attribute set for each product.