# How to hide the tab when no value is entered in the text field?

Tags: magento-1.9, tabs, magento-community

I have added a `text-field` attribute in product-collateral tab in details page with following code:

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<?php $Application = $_product->getApplication(); ?>
<?php if(count($Application, 'strlen') > 0): ?>

        <div class="application">
            <?php echo $_product->getApplication(); ?>
        </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

when I enter the value in the text field at backend it is perfectly getting displayed. But the error is that the tab is getting displayed even when I enter no value in that field.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide empty attribute in any magento template?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29469/how-to-hide-empty-attribute-in-any-magento-template)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question because OP is asking for pointing out issue with the given code where as referenced question seeks for a general solution for showing attribute even if it has no values set in admin section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but if you just want to hide the custom attribute when there is no content then you can use this.

```
$application = $_product->getApplication();
if (!is_null($application)):
echo '<div class="application">' . $application . '</div>';
endif;
```

You would use the same method around the tab data

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a small piece of code. Find and open the `attributes.phtml` file. This file can be found here: `/app/design/frontend/[theme name]/[package name]/template/catalog/product/view/attribute.phtml`

Open the file and search for the following lines:

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Replace the entire foreach loop with the following lines of code:

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```